# Mapping over Immutable.js Records

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

How do you best apply functions such as map when you have a Record?

This is the best I've got so far:

```
const FooRecord = Record({a: 0, b: 0})
const someRecord = FooRecord({a: 1, b: 2})
const someSeq = someRecord.toSeq().map(x => x + 1)
const someRecordUpdated = FooRecord(someSeq)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Records are lacking some of the collection api functions like `withMutations`, so I guess your approach is perfectly fine. I guess you asked because it looks weird, so maybe you prefer this one:

You could use [`mergeWith`](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record/mergeWith), which let's you define a merger function, an just pass in the same record as second collection:

```
const someRecordUpdated = someRecord.mergeWith(
    (originalVal, passedInVal) => originalVal + 1, someRecord);
```